# Can not receive push notifications from other servers since upgrade to 4.4.0

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, android, notification, push

Apart from using SalesForce for our marketing notifications, we have internal service related notifications which is sent by our own AWS based push notification servers.

With version "compile 'com.exacttarget.etpushsdk:etsdk:4.1.1@aar'" this was working as expected.

We have to upgrade to 4.4.0 recently due to other libraries upgrades (especially google libs), and after necessary codes changes to use 4.4.0, we CAN NO LONGER receive notifications sent from our AWS based servers!

Since upgraded to 4.4.1, we have to put ETPushService before other services, so that registration works. But we do have our custom GcmListenerService (subclass of it) defined in AndroidMenifest.xml and now it is no longer be able receive notifications that was working in 4.1.1!

Please help here, and this is very urgent, we have a relase in one week, and this is a blocker!

Many Thanks!!
Minghui Liu

Comment: Please open a support case with your account manager to get your issue into the correct hands and appropriately prioritized.

Comment: Please open a support case.  Our escalations team will be able to research your issue but we're going to need some specifics including your MID.

Comment: I'm sorry your question was flagged as off-topic.  I have no way to undo that, but I can assure you that an internal escalation for this issue has been created and the problem is being addressed.